# Cocos2d: CGRect, UITouch - Object/Class not detecting a location within its bounds

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uitouch, cgrect

I'm creating a CGRect within a class (Path).  I've verified that the the class is creating the rectangle.  Now, I've built a method into the class that should, in theory, return true when asked if a touch location is within the rectangle.  Problem is, it always returns false.  I've verified that the method is getting the touch, as needed.  Relevant code below:

Path.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Path : CCSprite {
    CGPoint startP;
    CGPoint endP;
    CGRect pathRect;
    CGPoint touchP;
}

-(id)initWithPoints:(CGPoint)sP :(CGPoint)eP;
-(bool)touchWithinBounds:(CGPoint)touch;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint startP;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint endP;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect pathRect;
@end
```

Path.mm

```
#import "Path.h"

@implementation Path

@synthesize startP;
@synthesize endP;
@synthesize pathRect;

-(id) initWithPoints:(CGPoint)sP :(CGPoint)eP {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        startP = sP;
        endP = eP;
        pathRect = CGRectMake(startP.x-2, endP.y, 5, 480);
    }
    return self;
}

-(bool)touchWithinBounds:(CGPoint)touch {
    touchP = touch;
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([self pathRect], touch)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

-(void) draw {
    glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glLineWidth(5.0f);
    ccDrawLine(startP, endP);
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In my main game scene, I initialize a path and add it to a mutable array:

```
paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        Path *path1 = [[[Path alloc] initWithPoints:ccp(winSize.width/3, 0.0) :ccp(winSize.width/3, winSize.height)] autorelease];
        [self addChild:path1 z:0];
        [paths addObject:path1];
```

And then in ccTouchesBegan, I send the touch location to touchWithinBounds.  But instead of reporting true when the rectangle is touched, it always reports false:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: [touch locationInView:touch.view ]];
    for (Path *path in paths) {
        CCLOG(@"%d", [path touchWithinBounds:location]);
```

Is there some kind of connection I'm missing between the pieces, or am I misunderstanding how the interaction works all-together?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had the points I was originating my rectangle at wrong.